# Android: Printing Bitmaps/PDF directly via WIFI

Tags: android, pdf, printing

I know there is `PrintManager` since Android 4.4.1, but is it possible to print a Bitmap or a PDF directly over WIFI without using the `PrintManager` at all (and therefore without user interaction)? I got it working using a `Socket` on Port 9100, but this is Text only.
Does anyone knows a specific printer (not a label printer) which accepts PDF or Bitmaps over WIFI?

Answer (score 1):

The statement in Peter's answer: *"All AirPrint Printers are required to accept PDF via IPP"* is not correct.

Apple strongly ***recommends*** to printer vendors to support PDF (but does ***not require*** it) when vendors implement AirPrint and want to qualify for the official AirPrint label.

But what Apple ***requires*** for AirPrint are these 4 conditions:

1. The printer must support IPP-2.0.
2. The printer must be able to accept and process JPEG.
3. The printer must be able to accept and process a special raster format which was developed by Apple (MIME type `image/urf`).
4. The printer must be able to announce its capabilities via DNS-SD (DNS Service Discovery) and mDNS (multicast DNS) standard protocols, a.k.a. "Bonjour".

Comment: Why the downvote? Which part of the answer is wrong? Why not comment and give a well-justified reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Most IPP and [AirPrint Printers](https://support.apple.com/de-de/HT201311) accept PDF.

IPP is based on HTTP with binary encoded messaging (IPP-Request/Response). You can use an implemention of the [IPP protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2910) in order to send the pdf straight to the printer:

e.g. https://github.com/gmuth/ipp-client-kotlin